# how produce image of face working with AI

Tags: image-processing

I came across a https://generated.photos/ site that claims to produce images entirely by artificial intelligence.
My question is how does this program work? What mechanism and libraries should I use if I want to do a project like this?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange. Your question is very broad. So, the question can be closed. Please click [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to check how to ask a nice question.

Comment: You can search [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-generation) and [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generative-adversarial-networks?tab=Votes)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [information](https://generated.photos/faq) from the site:

> We have built a proprietary dataset by taking tens of thousands of
> images of people in our studio. These photos are taken in a controlled
> environment allowing us to make sure that each face has consistent
> look and quality. After shooting, photos are tagged, categorized, and
> added to a dataset that is used for machine learning training. In an
> on-going fashion we feed this dataset into **generative adversarial**
> **networks** to produce faces that have never existed. Further machine
> learning processes take place after the faces are created in order to
> identify and remove flawed faces. The final results are made available
> through our website or API integration.

The algorithm they use is a [generative adversarial network](https://paperswithcode.com/method/gan). A sota architecture today is [StyleGAN2](https://paperswithcode.com/method/stylegan2) or, a new version of it, [Alias-Free GAN](https://nvlabs.github.io/alias-free-gan/).

Here is a live demo of StyleGAN2: https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/

And here is the official PyTorch implementation: https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2